# Regular polygon and tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tkz-euclide

Is there any slick way to create an n-sided (n is some arbitrary integer, e.g. n = 23) regular polygon, inscribed into a circle, using [`tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide)?

Or do I have to use the plain TikZ functions (not as intuitive as `tkz-euclide`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I find your lack of faith disturbing...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1xAUfdK9FE)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=23,draw,minimum height=5cm] (a) at (0,0) {};
\draw[red] let \p1=($(a.corner 1)-(a.center)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in circle (\n1);
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {A,B,...,W}{
  \node (a-\xi) at ([shift={({90+(\xi-1)*360/23}:3mm)}]a.corner \xi) {\x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And if I'd like to label the vertices A,B,C,...? What should be added then?

Comment: @marmistrz Added.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain how the lines 6-8 work?

Comment: Nice (+1)! I had no idea the `...` syntax could handle alphabetic sequences automatically.

Comment: @marmistrz It goes through every corner anchor which TikZ automatically numbers starting from the top. Then it places a node at each of those but instead placing them right on the anchor it shifts them the amount of 23 degrees depending on the number of iteration which is held in `\xi`. It's just a compact notation trust me nothing fancy happening.

Answer (score 6):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-poly`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-poly) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-poly}

% parameters
\def\radius{4}
\def\sides{12}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[dimen = m](-\radius,-\radius)(\radius,\radius)
  \rput(0,0){\PstPolygon[PolyNbSides = \sides, unit = \radius]}
  \pscircle(0,0){\radius}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: +1 for not threatening the use of the dark side of the force

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't follow you but I'm glad I haven't used 'the dark side of the force'. `:)`

Comment: See the link at the top of the other answer:-)

Answer (score 3):

A MetaPost solution using a macro of my own. Example shamelessly inspired from Svend Tveskæg's answer.

```
\documentclass[border=2bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef regular_polygon(expr center, radius, n) =
    save angl; angl := 360/n;
    (right for i = 1 upto n-1: -- dir(i*angl) endfor -- cycle) 
        scaled radius shifted center
enddef;
beginfig(0);
    draw regular_polygon(origin, 4cm, 12);
    draw fullcircle scaled 8cm;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Edit** Another version, a bit more elaborated, with alphabetic labels. The number of summits `n` must be lower than 27 to keep the labeling coherent :-)

```
\documentclass[border=2bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef regular_polygon(expr centre, radius, n) =
    clearxy; save angl; angl := 360/n; 
    z0 = centre + radius*right; freelabel("$A$", z0, centre); 
    z0 for i = 1 upto n-1:
        hide(z[i] = z[i-1] rotatedaround(centre, angl); 
            freelabel("$" & char(65+i) & "$", z[i], centre)) 
        -- z[i] 
    endfor -- cycle
enddef;
beginfig(0);
    draw regular_polygon(origin, 4cm, 12) withcolor red;
    draw fullcircle scaled 8cm;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]